# What are the differences between "know", "know about", and "know of"?

Tags: difference

I am confused about the differences between *know*, *know about*, and *know of*. Why do they use different prepositions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Level of knowledge.

> I know the C language. I can write programs in it proficiently. I know the caveats and problems.
>
> I know about Python. Basics of syntax, general structure. Given some time and references I might write some simple programs in it, but saying "I know Python" would be too much.
>
> I know of Haskell. There is such a language and it's a functional language. That's about all I know of it.

Answer (score 1):

Even the unqualified verb "know" is weak: depending on your proficiency, use verbs phrases like "am proficient in", "have use on several development projects...". in the field of programming "know" is an vague verb: I *know* the grammar of C, but have I developed in C?